# redirect to another controller after getting pk

Tags: yii

I am looking to redirect after form is submitted successfully. Save successfully from model 1, then use that pk to the fk in model 2. Originally I had widgets/components. But I am having an increasing number of these widgets and would like to look for another solution.

I've also tried `$this->redirect(array('controller/action', 'id'=>$model->id));` but the problem with this is that the id shows in the url. I don't like that either.

Is there another way other than these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an idea you can use `states` in Yii.
After saving model and getting the ID you can act like below:

```
//save done
Yii::app()->user->setState('id',$THE_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS);
Yii::app()->request->redirect('YOUR DESTINATION');
```

Then in your destination, You can use the ID you have set via `state`

```
if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('id')){
$id=Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
}
```

Another solution is using Yii's `Flash`. The difference between `state` and `flash` is that flash will be empty after one usage. If you want to use your ID only one time this is a good solution.
Just like `state`:

```
//save done
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('id',$THE_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS);
Yii::app()->request->redirect('YOUR DESTINATION');
```

Then in your destination, You can use the ID you have set via `flash`

```
if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('id')){
$id=Yii::app()->user->getFlash('id');
}
```

I hope this will be helpful to you.